# YAML validation against multiple JSON schemas

Tags: json, yaml, schema

I'm trying to check a yaml file against one or more JSON schema(s).
I'm looking to specify schemas to be checked against as part of my yaml file header.
Interest about is to get validation check running on a single file which may fulfill multiple non overlapping requirements. My high level need is to open some primary standard to some extension(s) which may be described Thanks additional dedicated schema(s).

I'm new if yaml not aware at all if such is possible or not ... please advise ! Any other possible way to fulfill my need ? Feel free !

I've got a try based on VSCode & RedHat dedicated extension. Up to now only first promoted schema is taken into account. I've no intellisense running based on second schema.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved Thanks `allOf`, `anyOf`, ... keywords usage (Thanks https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-yaml/issues/702)

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @ViktorIvliiev I agree. Update done. Thanks.